# Android - icons for each layout?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, icons

I've been building my app but have run into an issue I could use some insight on. I have two layout pages and in my emulator and real device its creating an icon for each one. I had temporarily solved this issue before by manually creating my menu and its items in the java file. Before - adding menu XML files was creating independent icons as well. I fixed that issue. Now the issue has returned but not related to the action bar menu items just the layout themselves.

This may be simple but thought I'd ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand your problem , then I think you have declared multiple launcher in manifest

Comment: Does your app needs two launcher activity or you want to show different icons on your activity's title?

Comment: Hey I was thinking about that but it looked the same as always so I may have ignored it. I'm going to check that StinePike.  it needs two activities but u cab get to it from action bar. @IrobBlossom